# Determine Trim on a Saab 9-5

Tags: saab, 9-5

I've a used saab and I need to determine the Trim for Amazon.com's car maintenance section.

Here's a picture of it: [image]

I really don't know how to determine the Trim.  Amazon wants to know if its a:

- 2.3t
- Aero
- SE

I seem to think it is the 2.3t from the Model being : 9-55D2.3LPT4CYL

Its stock number is 1312

Comment: Your best bet is always to go with the VIN number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to jot down your [VIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number) number and plug it into a VIN decoder (check out [saabnet.com](http://www.saabnet.com/tsn/models/) for starters).

Answer (score 1):

The VIN (Vehicle Identification Number) will tell you everything you need to know. You can check it on this page: http://vin-location.com

The VIN will be visible from the outside on the bottom drivers side of the windshield, and inside on the sticker in the drivers door sill. You may also find trim level information on that same sticker.